# reversing django object query with parent-child M2M relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

in a case with three models (objects) with this type of object relationship:

```
# Team = parent, a group or collection of people
class Team(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True) 
      ...

# Person = an individual person who belongs to a team
class Person(models.Model):
     # relationships
     team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='people')
     projects = SortedManyToManyField('Project', related_name='people')


 # Project = each Person can have zero, one, or multiple Projects
 # multiple different teams can work on same Project
 class Project(TimeStampedModel):
       TYPES = Choices( ... )
```

I know I can query "People with Projects on a Team" like this:

```
user_teams = Team.objects.filter(user=request.user, ...)
people_with_projects = Person.objects.filter(team__in=user_teams, projects=True)
```

how would I reverse that relationship to get the queryset for "list of Projects People who are on Team Foo are working on"? (i.e., Projects by specific Team).

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood what you're trying to do correctly, this would work:

```
team_foo = Team.objects.get(name="Foo")
projects = Project.objects.filter(people__team=team_foo).distinct()
```

Or just:

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(people__team__name="Foo").distinct()
```

That should give you all the projects where someone from team Foo is working on.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#first we get the specific team
team = Team.objects.get(name='Foo',...)
#then enumerate the persons in the team
persons = Person.objects.filter(team=team)
#finally make an array of the projects by person:
projects = []
for person in persons:
    resObj = {}
    resObj['person'] = person.name
    resObj['projects'] = person.projects
    projects.append(resObj)
```

I think that should do, not 100% sure though.